# Not parsing variable correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have this method, that it return me a time value in NSString.

```
- (NSString *) date:(NSString *)lafecha;
{

    NSString *dateStr = lafecha;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSTimeInterval comparacion = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSMutableString *returnDate;

    //positiveValue
    int comparacionInHours = abs(comparacion / 3600);

    //returning the correct date
    if (comparacionInHours < 1) {
        NSLog(@"%d mins ago", (comparacionInHours / 60));
        returnDate = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d mins ago", (comparacionInHours / 60)];
        return returnDate;
    }
    else if ((comparacionInHours > 1) && (comparacionInHours < 24)) {
        NSLog(@"%d hours ago", (comparacionInHours));
        returnDate = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", (comparacionInHours)];
        return returnDate;
    }
    else if (comparacionInHours > 24) {
        NSLog(@"%@", date);
        return returnDate;
    }
    else {
        return returnDate;

    }
}
```

When I try to get the return value, it always returns me zero.

```
NSMutableString *stringDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];


for (NSDictionary *story in stories){

    stringDate = [story objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self date:stringDate]);
}
```

If I try with a simple NSString date like "**Wed, 01 Jan 2014 17:05:13 +0000**" it works, but 
when I do it inside the enumeration it does not work.

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `[story objectForKey:@"pubDate"]`?  What is it?

Comment: The values are like this, all of them **Wed, 01 Jan 2014 17:05:13 +0000**

Comment: Print about a dozen of them and post them here.

Comment: `Reader[18143:70b] Wed, 01 Jan 2014 17:05:13 +0000 
Reader[18143:70b] Mon, 30 Dec 2013 22:23:37 +0000
Reader[18143:70b] Mon, 30 Dec 2013 21:21:39 +0000
Reader[18143:70b] Fri, 02 Aug 2013 15:05:22 +0000
Reader[18143:70b] Sat, 06 Jul 2013 15:13:51 +0000
Reader[18143:70b] Tue, 02 Jul 2013 17:05:01 +0000`

Comment: Normally you should use MMMM, not LLLL, for the month.  Not clear that it should make a difference, though.

Comment: If I try it with a variable like this `NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:54:10 +0000";`

IT work, so the problem is not on the function. I also use an NSXML Parser

Comment: Try doing `setLenient:YES` on the date formatter.

Comment: Ah, XML.  Strip "whitespace" from your dates before parsing.  There are newlines and tabs in there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46561/discussion-between-user3241911-and-hot-licks)

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs look like "Wed, 01 Jan 2014 17:05:13 +0000" (from your comment), then your date format string should be `"EEE, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: "EE" should work fine, according to [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  But you're right that it probably should be "LLL" (or "MMM").

Comment: Thats not really the problem, since I tested it with

        `NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:54:10 +0000";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
        
        NSTimeInterval comparacion = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];`

And it worked perfectly.